# React Native showing blank screen. No errors in the console

Tags: react-native

My react native code builds correctly, and I have no errors. However the code fails to show anything on the screen. Any pointers as what I could be doing wrong? I have checked the code multiple times and searched for countless hours online. Still not finding anything.

```
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, Image, View, StatusBar, SafeAreaView } from 'react-native';

const HomeScreen = () => {
    return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
            <SafeAreaView>
                <View style={styles.profile}>
                    <Text style={styles.name}>Home Screen</Text>
                    <Image
                        source={require('../../assets/images/tree_sunset.jpg')} 
                        style={styles.imageProfile}
                    />
                </View>
            </SafeAreaView>
        </View>
    );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        flex: 1,
    },
    profile: {
        flexDirection: 'row',
        backgroundColor: '#EEE',
    },
    imageProfile: {
        width: 34,
        marginBottom: 5,
        marginTop: 5,
        borderRadius: 44/2,
        marginLeft: 10,
        height: 34
    },
    name: {
        alignSelf: 'center',
        marginLeft: 10,
        fontSize: 130
    }
});

export default HomeScreen
```

Comment: The code should be fine. I have tested it using an Expo Snack and I successfully see the `Home Screen` text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Check the component hierarchy: Make sure that the component is being rendered and is part of the component hierarchy. You can use the React DevTools or console.log statements to check the component tree.
2. Check the styling: Verify that the styling is correct, and the component is not being hidden by other components or styles. You can try adding a background color to the container or profile view to see if the component is being rendered.
3. Check the dimensions: Verify that the dimensions of the components are correct and that they are not being clipped or hidden. You can use the React DevTools to inspect the dimensions of the components.
4. Check the device or emulator: Check if the issue occurs on both iOS and Android devices or emulators. It is possible that the issue is specific to a particular platform or device.
5. Try simplifying the code: Remove any unnecessary code and try to simplify the component to the minimum required to display the content. This can help in identifying the root cause of the issue.
6. Check for issues with importing the required components or assets.

Comment: This helped me a lot. I found out the problem was with the way I was using safe area view.